# remove duplicates while combining System.IO.FileInfo objects

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to combine System.IO.FileInfo objects (from distinct Get-ChildItem calls) together. I've found working solutions (i.e. using PowerShell array) from this question:
[Combine the results of two distinct Get-ChildItem calls into single variable to do the same processing on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749979/combine-the-results-of-two-distinct-get-childitem-calls-into-single-variable-to)

```
$target = "C:\example"

$Files = @( Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $target -Force -Attributes !D )
$Files += @( Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $target -Force -Attributes !D ) # for demo. & simplicity, I'm using the same path here

$Files | Write-Host # here the same entries are duplicated
```

However, the same entries from the System.IO.FileInfo objects are duplicated in the resulting object. I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to combine the objects while removing the duplicates?

PS: Files are "duplicated" if they have the same ".FullName".

Comment: Define "duplicate".  Your comment suggests each call to `Get-ChildItem` will be passed a different `-LiteralPath`, so what constitutes a duplicate file?  Same name, relative path, contents/hash, or something else?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question (Files are "duplicated" if they have the same ".FullName". )

Comment: Is one path passed to `Get-ChildItem` an ancestor of the other? Even then, without `-Recurse` the output file objects can never have the same `FullName`. Please show an actual sample of what you want to run because your `# for demo. & simplicity, I'm using the same path` comment isn't making things more clear.  As written, if you don't want duplicate `FileInfo`s then simply _don't call `Get-ChildItem` twice_.

Comment: thx for the reply, filimonic's answer already solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
$Files = @($Files | Sort-Object -Property FullName -Unique)
```